# What interesting mathematical identities (or theorems) have been proven using quaternions?

Tags: big-list, quaternions

I've heard about the four square theorem and how it was proven using quaternions, which I found to be extremely fascinating, I was wondering whether there are any other interesting theorems which seem to have nothing to do with quaternions that were proven with quaternions, I looked up online but couldn't find any other than four square theorem, and there must be more. Thanks!

Comment: The usual approach for the proof of the four square theorem is infinite descent and Lagrange's idendity. It would be interesting to see the proof via quaternions.

Comment: @Peter I would say it's a really really interesting proof and was looking for other proofs like that one which used quaternions, the proof basically goes as follows: A positive integer will be a sum of four squares if it is the norm of a Hurwitz Integer (since the norm would be the sum of the squares of a, b, c, d), due to the multiplicativity of the norm then what is left to do is prove that every prime is the sum of four squares (a Hurwitz Integer norm), which they prove using the sum of two squares (another really interesting proof which I believe also uses quaternions).

Comment: There are a number of related results about ternary and quaternary quadratic forms one can prove with quaternion algebras.  There are also some much more advanced results about applications of quaternions to modular forms, elliptic curves and L-functions.  In another more geometric direction, one relatively elementary book that might be of interest is Conway and Smith's _On quaternions and octonions_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem:** There is a surjective group homomorphism from the group $SU(2)$ of all $2\times2$ complex unitary matrices with determinant $1$ onto the group $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ of all $3\times3$ orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$.

**Sketch of proof:** See $SU(2)$ as$$\left\{a+bi+cj+dk\in\mathbb H\,\middle|\,a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\right\}.$$Let$$\operatorname{Im}\mathbb H=\left\{\alpha i+\beta j+\gamma k\,\middle|\,\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$Then, for each $q\in SU(2)$ and each $r\in\operatorname{Im}\mathbb H$, $qrq^{-1}\in\operatorname{Im}\mathbb H$. It turns out that the linear map $r\mapsto qrq^{-1}$ has determinant $1$. Furthermore, it preserves the quaternionic norm. So, we can see this map as en element of $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ and this map from $SU(2)$ into $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ is actually surjective (and its kernel is $\pm\operatorname{Id}$).

Comment: how would you show the kernel is {1, -1}? I am not good at all in group theory so I am trying to improve.

Comment: If $q$ belongs the kernel, then $qrq^{-1}=r$ for each $r\in\operatorname{Im}\mathbb H$. In other words, $q$ commutes with every element of $\operatorname{Im}\mathbb H$. But it also commutes with every real number. Therefore, it commutes with every quaternion. But the only quaternins which commute with every quaternion are the real numbers and the only real numbers with norm $1$ are $\pm1$.

Comment: How would you show the map is surjective however? I took a break for a while but I still can't seem to show this. BTW this is relatively urgent.

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be the map that I defined. Then $\varphi\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$ is a rotation around the line $i\mathbb R$ with angle $2\theta$, $\varphi\bigl(\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)\bigr)$ is a rotation around the line $j\mathbb R$ with angle $2\theta$, and $\varphi\bigl(\cos(\theta)+k\sin(\theta)\bigr)$ is a rotation around the line $k\mathbb R$ with angle $2\theta$. On the other hand, $SO(3,\mathbb R)$ is spanned by the rotations around those $3$ axes.

Comment: Sorry, I am slightly confused, doesn't the map  have a domain of Im(H), meaning pure quaternions? Hence wouldn't the cos() not be correct? I know I am definitely missing something but I simply can't figure out what it is.

Comment: My map $\varphi$ is a map from $SU(2)$ into $SO(\mathbb R,3)$.

Comment: Your map is    : ↦^−1 right? And just a quick question what matrix did you get for this linear map?

Comment: No. For each $q\in SU(2)$, $\varphi(q)$ is the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi(q)\colon&\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb H)&\longrightarrow&\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb H)\\&r&\mapsto&qrq^{-1}.\end{array}$$

Comment: Ah okay. Do you have a matrix for this map btw? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. That matrix of $\varphi(a+bi+cj+dk)$ with respect to the basis $\{i,j,k\}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2&2(-ad+bc)&2(ac+bd)\\2(ad+bc)&a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2&2(-ab+cd)\\2(-ac+bd)&2(ab+cd)&a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2\end{bmatrix}.$$Besides, if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes I did, thanks!! How did you get this matrix with respect to {i, j, k}?

Comment: I computed it. All you have to do to obtain its first column is to compute $\varphi(a+bi+cj+dk)(i)$ and to write it as $\alpha i+\beta j+\gamma k$; then the entries of the first column will be $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. And you do the same thing to obtain the other columns.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I seem to be getting the signs flipped in some of the elements of the matrix, eg. 2(ad-bc) instead 2(ad+bc). Do you know if there's any chance you did a computational error or did I? Thanks!

Comment: I think that my computations are correct. Note that I got basically the same matrix as the one that you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Using_quaternions_of_unit_norm).